# why xcode prompts to save files for all projects

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios4

Is there a way to set XCode that it won't attempt to save files from a project is not being build/run?

When you have several open projects, say project A, and project B. You change files in project A, then change files in project B. Then, build project B; at this point, XCode will ask you if you want to save changes made to files for project A.
It's ok that XCode asks me if I want to save changes in files for project B, but doesn't make sense that asks me if I want to save change in files for project A, because that project is not even being built, less run and more still, both projects are at all related.

-Carlos